# Use loggers with Celery in business-logic module

Tags: python, logging, celery

The examples given in the [Celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging) are too simple:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    logger.info('Adding {0} + {1}'.format(x, y))
    return x + y
```

Fine, I can use the celery task logger directly in the task. But what happens if my celery task is using complex business logic, like importing from another module, which is doing some logging too?

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    from business import complex_addition
    return complex_addition(x, y)
```

And in `business.py`:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('business')

def complex_addition(x, y):
    res = x + y*7 - x*4 + x**2
    logger.info('res=%s', res)
    return res
```

But this logger is not showing anything. How can I get a celery compatible logger in my business module, when it does not even know that it is running in a Celery context?

Ideally all setup should be done at the task level, and the business module should be left unchanged, since it can run as part of a celery task or in any other kind of context. Can this be done?